# PIR Sensor Triggering Script Doesnt Loop

Tags: python

I'm using trying to create a living portrait that triggers by motion. The idea is a pi4b connected to a lcd monitor that displays a picture. On motion the picture kicks over to video and morphs. Its a halloween thing that I got from here:

https://www.hackster.io/dominick-marino/possessed-portrait-updated-32a7a6

This code uses omxplayer and I am going with the recommended player VLC. What I am trying to do is a little different.

1. The script starts on boot, the video is started and then paused thereby creating a still image
2. On motion the video is resumed and the loop plays to the end. The idea is the script queues back up for another run. Ive got a code issue. The script will execute, it will detect motion and start the video, it does not loop.

I appreciate any guidance. Thank you in advance.
Here is the main code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
        from time import sleep
        import vlc
        from pirDetect import *
        import sys

        #variables

        vlc_instance = vlc.Instance()
player = vlc_instance.media_player_new()
player.video_set_aspect_ratio("5:4")
player.set_fullscreen(True)
player.set_mrl("/home/mike/pi/test2.mp4")
player.play()
sleep(1)
player.set_pause(1)
#function for launching video
def onMotion(currState):
    if currState:
        player.play()
    while True:
        sleep(.1)

objDetect = detector(7)
objDetect.subscribe(onMotion)
objDetect.start()
```

Here is the code for motion detection:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import os

class detector(object):
    def __init__(self, sensor):
        self.callBacks = []
        self.sensor = sensor
        self.currState = False
        self.prevState = False
        GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
        GPIO.setup(self.sensor, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)

    def read(self):
        self.prevState = self.currState
        self.currState = GPIO.input(self.sensor)

    def printState(self):
        print( "GPIO pin {0} is {1}".format(self.sensor, "HIGH" if self.currState else "LOW"))

    def subscribe(self, callBack):
        self.callBacks.append(callBack)

    def callBack(self, state):
        for fn in self.callBacks:
            fn(state)

    def start(self):
        try:
            self.read()
            self.printState()
            while True:
                self.read()
                if self.currState != self.prevState:
                    self.printState()
                    self.callBack(self.currState)
                    time.sleep(.1)

        except(KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
                    #Since fbi doesn't restore the console correctly when the application is exited we do a little clean up.
            os.system('stty sane')
```

Comment: your code is not formatted correctly

Comment: @jsotola Thanks for the reply, much appreciated. I realize the indentation didnt come out  right when I pasted it, may I ask what else is wrong? I'm a python noob.

Comment: @stargazerdood I working on the same project. Did you get it running in a loop now? Can you share your code?